# Applying rotation mess up model

Tags: modeling

I made a model with armature and animations.Everything was working fine in unity but axis y and z were swapped. So i went back to blender and tried to apply rotation but it totally messe up model. Im not sure what exactly "rotation to deltas" does but i tried and it seems like rotation was applied correctly but i axis are still wrong in unity.

[image]
[image]

Comment: If it's not the keyboard layout use Ctrl+Shift.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to apply a pose of a rigged character is: pose the model in its desired rest pose; select the mesh and apply its armature modifier; select the armature and in pose mode select all bones and press Ctrl A "Apply pose as rest pose"; add to the mesh a new armature modifier, pointing a the armature rig.

This procedure will not affect the weights, but can destroy any previously made animation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that bad armature connections were causing the trouble.I deleted previous armature  and made a new one.everything works fine now.